# Load latest flat file from folder to database tables using SQL queries

Tags: sql-server

I have four flat files example `Employee1.txt`, `Employee2.txt`, `Employee3.txt`, `Employee4.txt`, and the first flat file is copied on January month, 2nd flat file on February month 3rd flat file on March month and 4th flat file on April month so.

Now I wanted to load April month flat file to SQL tables using the only SQL queries not with SSIS.

Comment: Can you please define SQL server version? .. Many features vary based on version!

Comment: There is no way to get flatfile timestamp. better you create `batch` file and write your logic to identify latest filename and share the output as a parameter to your SQL query, it might work!

Comment: Yes Irfan you are right, can I have the complete query step by step query using batch

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the ‘’’bulk insert’’’ functionality in SQL SERVER.

EXAMPLE

```
BULK INSERT Sales
FROM 'C:\1500000 Sales Records.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n' );
```

Of note, you have to be on point with the schemas or it will fail.

REFERENCE:  https://codingsight.com/sql-server-bulk-insert-part-1/

Comment: I need based on the modified date in the folder example 4 flat files in a folder and have to load the latest modified date flat file

Comment: This would then take several steps.  1. Make a staging table for loading of data.  2. If you know the folder pattern, and can anticipate what the foldername will look like, Create a Stored Procedure to dynamically create the `BULK INSERT` statement and execute it.  3. Once loaded into the staging table, and before the next file is loaded, create a merge statement, using the month the folder represents as a "LAST LOAD DATE" field added enroute to the actual table.  Use the MERGE to perform UPSERT.  IF you can't determine foldernames, then you will need a third party.  SSIS or python are my fav.

Comment: The staging table is truncated and loaded per file.